# Скомпилированная программа не работает

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Здравствуйте! Бьюсь уже не первый день, в интернете решения не нашел. Есть IDE CodeBlocks. Есть компилятор GNU. Компилятор на IDE установлен. Компилирую любой код, например Hello World, программа создается с расширением .exe и открывается в консоли. По идее в консоли должно выводиться "Hello World" но этого не происходит... Проблема наблюдалась и с Visual Studio. CodeBlocks переустанавливал несколько раз, компилятор тоже.
Операционная система: Windows 7x64
В compiler settings ни одной галочки не активировано. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не знаком с этой средой, но попробуйте добавить `cin.get();` после `cout`. Вполне возможно, что стартовая консоль отображает всё, что Вы попросили и закрывается, а остаётся некая вспомогательная

Comment: У вас зоопарка антивирусов часом не установлено? 
Дата на компьютере не ездит?

Comment: Дата не ездит. "Животных" дома не держу. Разве что рыбку Avast. Но...ничосибе. Я только что выкинул эту рыбку в окно, и... программа скомпилировалась и запустилась! Как же банально... Спасибо, gbg!

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте внимательно лог сборки - ваша программа не собирается:

> Target is up to date
>
> Nothing to be done

ГлюкиБлокс берут какой-то старый экзешник и запускают.

Comment: Он мог взять скриншот с ~10 запуска программы, конечно там нечего собирать — нужно просто запустить